# Send HTTP Requests only if API returns desired response

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to implement a logic where i do not want to send HTTP Requests unless an API returns 0 for a field. If i send the requests without monitoring response from this API, my test is invalid. 
API returns response in JSON, i can parse and extract the data i need to compare.

Below is my test structure
    Thread Group
     - CSV Data Set Config
     - HTTP Request
     - JSON Path Assertion

I want to call this API after every minute and proceed with sending HTTP Requests when field value is 0. I don't want to check before every HTTP Request just once before sending the first request.

Should i use If-controller and JSR223 preprocessor (for invoking API, parsing JSON etc) but pre-processor will be invoked before every request which is too much overhead and not required. 
Please let me know if you have any suggestions. 
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Re-design your plan as follows:

- Thread Group

  - [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)

    - CSV Data Set Config
    - HTTP Request
    - JSON Path Extractor
    - [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)
  - While Controller Condition: `${__javaScript("${somevar}" != "0",)}`
  - Constant Throughput Timer: Target Throughput - `1.0`